# Faster Background Image in OpenGLES

Tags: android, opengl-es, background-image

I'm writing a game in Android/OpenGLES, and when I use traceview, I see that the time taken to draw my background image (using glDrawTexfOES) is quite huge.

I understand of course that as the background fills the screen, it should take longer than my other sprites, but is there a faster way to draw the background image. The background does not move or change during the game, so maybe there is a tip or trick to do it faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, I believe it's faster to do what you want by drawing and texturing a quad(well, or a triangle strip) using a texture buffer. I don't have any solid benchmarks, but it made a pretty big difference for me. Mine was a lot of smaller images(font renderer) rather than one large one, but faster is faster in my experience.